# convergence in probability of division and their expected values

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $\frac{X_n}{Y_n} \rightarrow 1$ in probability. Then does $\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_n]}{\mathbb{E}[Y_n]} \rightarrow 1$? If not, what are the conditions required for this to hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $(X_n,Y_n)$ be $(1,1)$ with probability $\frac{n-1}n$ and $(n+1,1)$ with probability $\frac1n$. Then $\frac{X_n}{Y_n}\to1$ in probability, but

$$
\frac{\mathbb E[X_n]}{\mathbb E[Y_n]}=2\;.
$$

I don't know what conditions would lead to $\frac{\mathbb{E}[X_n]}{\mathbb{E}[Y_n]} \rightarrow 1$.